# can I expand non-integer powers

Tags: factorization

How can I help Mma to recognize that `w` can be factored out of `(a w)^a (w - a w)^(1 - a)`.  Assumptions: w>0 and 1>a>0.

Comment: `FullSimplify[ExpandAll[(a w)^a (w - a w)^(1 - a)] , {w > 0 , 1 > a > 0}]` gets the `w` outside.

Comment: @Coolwater Thanks.  I had tried this with `PowerExpand` instead of `ExpandAll`, and that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Assuming[w > 0 && 1 > a > 0, 
 Collect[(a w)^a (w - a w)^(1 - a), w, Simplify]]
```

$\ $ `(1 - a)^(1 - a) a^a w`

---

```
Simplify[Cancel[(a w)^a (w - a w)^(1 - a)], Assumptions -> w > 0 && 1 > a > 0]
```

$\ $ `-(-1 + a) (a/(1 - a))^a w`

```
Simplify[Together[(a w)^a (w - a w)^(1 - a)], Assumptions -> w > 0 && 1 > a > 0]
```

$\ $ `-(-1 + a) (a/(1 - a))^a w`

```
Simplify[Factor[(a w)^a (w - a w)^(1 - a)], Assumptions -> w > 0 && 1 > a > 0]
```

$\ $ `-(-1 + a) (a/(1 - a))^a w`